# How could i get selected value from dropdownlist in kendo ui grid in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui

I am working on Kendo UI with asp.net mvc razor. I am trying to bind database table data with kendo grid that supports CRUD operations. Here i need to populate a dropdownlist for one of my table field. I have used the following code

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.PriceOption>    
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            //columns.Bound(p => p.ProductTitle).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled='disabled'name='Discontinued' <#= Discontinued? checked='checked' : '' #> />");
            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductTitle).EditorTemplateName("OptionalEmail");
            columns.Bound(p => p.OptionTitle);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Price);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Frequency);
            columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);



        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
            .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ProductID))
            .Create(create => create.Action("CreateOption", "ZiceAdmin"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "ZiceAdmin"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateOption", "ZiceAdmin"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("DeleteOption", "ZiceAdmin"))
        )
    )
```

**OptionalEmail.cshtml**

```
@model string
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ProductTitle")
    .Value(Model)
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductTitle))
 )
```

Here i need to store the selected item from the dropdownlist. But it always shows null. How could i get the selected value from dropdownlist.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bug. Remove the name, and it will submit back to the server as part of the `ViewModel`:

```
@model string 
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList() 
    .Value(Model) 
    .SelectedIndex(0) 
    .BindTo(new SelectList(ViewBag.ProductTitle)) 
 )
```

Comment: the name value needs to not be null.. Description: `An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

Exception Details: `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`